# Synonym for "New" in the "Whole Cloth" sense

Tags: single-word-requests

If I buy a "new" car, there is ambiguity.

My "new" car might be replacing my daily driver and this isn't very exciting.

My "new" car might might be a hotrod red Corvette and suddenly my "new" car is conveying not just a physically new car, but the promise of new experiences and even maybe a "new" (sexier, cooler) me.

How can I say the car is "new" to encapsulate the physical new + the spiritual new?

"Whole cloth" is the only other idiom I can come up with. I don't think it fits. Suggestions?

EDIT: We use the idiom "good-as-new" to describe the positive-aspiration of a repair, and we say "I'm a new person" after a positive spiritual experience. Somehow the idiomatic nature of these phrases we automatically associate with the spiritual positivity I am looking for. But not used idiomatically.

EDIT 2: Some examples:

If I say "I bought a new toy" my family understands I didn't actually buy a child's toy, rather I bought something inconsequential or hobby related that I hold in a positive regard maybe even with delusions of grandeur. This is another idiom, but see the next example.

It's common for people to say "I bought a new boat" not just to convey that they bought a boat, but with the subtext that "My 9-5 grind is over, I'm now about to live a life of adventure."

Or "I'm moving to a new house": while it *could* represent the physical condition, i.e. the old house is falling apart, it also represents "I'm financially secure, wanting room to expand, and my tastes have improved."

As I am pointing out, "new" is ambiguous. And in all of these cases, "new" is an adjective on the noun in which the adjective is subtextually about the speaker and not the noun. Does this make sense? Great!

Therefore, what is form of speech of "new" in those examples, and what is a less ambiguous word than new?

Comment: I'm surprised that you make no reference to whether or not the car you bought was previously owned. New-to-me and brand-new are differnet things. That said, I in no way understand *new* to mean exciting: a Corvette is no more or differently new than a Civic. And welcome to English Language & Usage! Glad to have you

Comment: You make a good point that the ambiguity of "new" extends to prior ownership, too. I would say that "new" as in "new-to-me", i.e. "I bought a new car" is some ambiguity in the positive sense: it may be used, but it makes me happy!

Comment: You mention a lot of senses of "new" in your question. Leaving it unclear to me which sense you are asking for in answers. Can you edit the question to make clear exactly what you want. Also please read the long description of the "single-word-requests" tag and be sure you have provided the information that's required.

Comment: Here's a link to the info on [how to ask a single-word-request question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). In particular, note that you need to include an example sentence showing how the word will be used. That lets us know whether you want a noun or an adjective or something else, and helps get across the nuance and register you want. more context and what terms you've considered (and why they don't work) are also extremely helpful.

Comment: Pragmatics demands that 'a new me' is read as being a radically changed version of the old me whereas the default readings of 'a new car' are 'never driven before' or 'to replace the old one'. You'd probably need to describe the effect a sensational new car had upon a person rather than find a better descriptor than 'inspirational'.